# Access a single element in large published array with Dask

Tags: dask, dask-delayed, dask-distributed

**Is there a faster way to only retrieve a single element in a large published array with Dask without retrieving the entire array?**

In the example below client.get_dataset('array1')[0] takes roughly the same time as client.get_dataset('array1').

```
import distributed
client = distributed.Client()
data = [1]*10000000
payload = {'array1': data}
client.publish(**payload)

one_element = client.get_dataset('array1')[0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that anything you publish goes to the scheduler, not to the workers, so this is somewhat inefficient.  Publish was intended to be used with Dask collections like dask.array.

#### Client 1

```
import dask.array as da
x = da.ones(10000000, chunks=(100000,))  # 1e7 size array cut into 1e5 size chunks
x = x.persist()  # persist array on the workers of the cluster

client.publish(x=x)  # store the metadata of x on the scheduler
```

#### Client 2

```
x = client.get_dataset('x')  # get the lazy collection x
x[0].compute()  # this selection happens on the worker, only the result comes down
```

Comment: I would like to mark this question as complete but, when I run this code snippet using the approach suggested, it hangs at a[0].compute().
For the actual code snippet I use, please see the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468673/using-dask-compute-causes-execution-to-hang

Comment: I was able to get the code snippet you posted working. In order to get it working I had to make sure that workers were also created for the scheduler b/c in my version. For anyone else, see my link above for more info.